# XQuery clause not yielding any results

Tags: xml, xquery, where-clause

The goal for this query is to print the list of employee names that live in San Fran.

Here is the clause I've written:

```
for $x in doc("data.xml")/EmpDatabase/PersonList/Person
where $x/City="San Fran"
order by $x/Name
return $x/Name
```

Here is the data's template schema (of which I've populated with data in my data.xml file):

```
<EmpDatabase>

<PersonList Type="Employee">
<Title Value="Employee List"/>
<Contents>
     <Person>
          <Name></Name>
          <Street></Street>
          <City></City>
     </Person>
</Contents>
</PersonList>

</EmpDatabase>
```

And here's how I'm running the query on the Windows command line:

```
java -jar kawa-1.9.1.jar --xquery -f emp.xquery -> results.xml
```

However, when I run this command, the command line acts as though the query was successful but results.xml is an empty file...

Can you take a look at this to see what I may be doing wrong in my xquery file? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for $x in doc("data.xml")//PersonList/Person[City/text() ="San Fran"]
order by $x/Name
return $x/Name/text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I believe this happened because I forgot the .../Contents/... in my original path name in the where clause. Thanks again!

Comment: The fact that an incorrect path gives no error, just an empty result , is a common problem with XPath and XQuery. You might consider using a schema-aware query processor: it's more effort to import a schema and declare your types, but the better diagnostics are well worth having.